# How to assign value to a char array (C-String) within C++ DLL through C# code

Tags: c#, c++, dll, char, dllexport

I have a DLL developed in C++ that performs some computations. I am trying to link this DLL into my C# application.

I have a struct within a struct which contains a char array (C string). I have a pointer to the object created by the C++ DLL within my C# application.

```
namespace Test
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct Child
    {
      public float number1;
      public float number2;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
      public char[] name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct DataStructure
    {
        public Child child;
        ...
    }
.
.
.
    public unsafe partial class Form1:Form {

        [DllImport("Calculation.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        unsafe public static extern IntPtr createInstance(); 

        [DllImport("Calculation.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        unsafe public static extern DataStructure* processData(IntPtr source);                    // Setup of data

        [DllImport("Calculation.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        unsafe public static extern int calculate(IntPtr calc);                                   // Perform calculation
.
.

    public Form2()
    {

         private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // test functions
            unsafe
            {
                IntPtr ptr1 = createInstance();                 // Returns pointer to the instance
                DataStructure* data = processData(ptr1);        // Returns pointer to DataStructure object created through DllImport

                data->child.number1 = 1.234F;                   // Works
                data->child.number1 = 9.876F;                   // Works

                data->child.name = "......"                     // This doesn't work!!

                int result = calculate(ptr1);                   // Returns value when name commented
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't comment `name`, I get the Error - Cannot take the address of managed object.
If I comment `name`, I am able to run the calculation without issue.

I wish to update the value of the char array `name` but can't seem to figure out the solution. Below is my usual C solution. Thanks!

```
#include "DataStructure.h"
#define DLLNAME "Calculation.dll"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibraryA(fileNameDll);

        const void* ptr1 = 0;
        int result = 0;
        DataStructure *data;

        ptr1 = createInstance();
        data = processData(ptr1);

        data->child.number1 = 1.234;
        data->child.number2 = 9.876;

        sprintf(data->child.name, "3104-03");

        result = calculate(ptr1);
}
```

Comment: Make name a string instead of char[].  In c a string is a byte[] (char in c# is two bytes).  The Marshal UnmanagedType.LPArray will automatically convert the c++ byte[] to a string.

Comment: @jdweng I tried that, but then I get a Error while compiling. `CS0208 - Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('DataStructure')`

Comment: Do not use "unsafe" it is not needed.  Remove all pointers.  Change : public static extern IntPtr processData(IntPtr source);   Then you will need to use Marshal to copy the DataStructure from un-managed to managed object.

Comment: @jdweng, the problem here is that creating a `DataStructure` object in C# and copying the values into it is not helpful, as the DLL uses only the `DataStructure` object created by itself. So the only way is to update the values through the pointer referencing the `DataStructure` object created by the DLL.

Comment: Wrong! Wrong! Wrong!.  In c# you modify the managed values.  Then copy Manage object to Un-manage memory.  Or when you return object copy from un-managed to managed to get return values.

Comment: I couldn't find a function in the DLL to explicitly copy the object from C# to the DLL object. But I will try out your recommendation from the previous comment. Sorry, I am completely new to C# and this interfacing.

Comment: Marshal.StructureToPtr(), and Marshal.PtrToStructure()